# Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find xpath "//a[@href']"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, xpath, capybara

I'm having this test

```
feature 'Edit post' do
  let(:post) { build(:post) }

  scenario 'can edit post' do
    visit root_path
    find(:xpath, "//a[@href='/posts/1']").click

    click_link 'Edit'

    fill_in 'Title', with: 'This is an updated post'
    click_button 'Save'

    expect(page).to have_content('Post was successfully updated')
    expect(page).to have_content('This is an updated post')
  end
end
```

when I run the test I get the following error which, as I understand, says that Capybara can't find the link

```
Failure/Error: find(:xpath, "//a[@href='/posts/1']").click

     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find xpath "//a[@href='/posts/1']"
```

However if I open the app on the browser I can click the `show` link from the `root_path` (index) and access the show action, which makes me think there's an error with my testing script. How can I fix this?

UPDATE
I did puts page.html, This is what I get

```
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Nihil neque corrupti atque qui eum omnis sapiente harum.</td>
<td>[&quot;Alias quas culpa expedita voluptatem vel. Eos aut autem tempora saepe odit iste. Iste ducimus dolorem a corrupti esse enim sint. Fugiat eum doloremque soluta ut voluptate sit. Nostrum unde in nobis quam ut adipisci quos cupiditate.&quot;, &quot;Fugiat voluptatem qui totam fugit culpa et. Id omnis repellendus labore mollitia earum dignissimos ipsum. Eum rem qui excepturi culpa aut. Cum adipisci aspernatur nulla qui odio. Sequi minima doloremque iure ea possimus maiores alias.&quot;]</td>
<td><a href="/articles/1">Show</a></td>
<td><a href="/articles/1/edit">Edit</a></td>
<td><a data-confirm="Are you sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/articles/1">Destroy</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<br>
<a href="/articles/new">New Article</a>

  </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `let` the object is lazily built.  That means it doesn't exist until you actually reference it once in the test.  Since you never reference it, it's never built and therefore doesn't exist. If you switch to `let!` in this case it will force it to build

```
let!(:post) { create(:post) }
```

The other issue you have is that you can't assume it will built with an id of 1, so you probably want to use the post id in your url

```
find(:xpath, ".//a[@href='/posts/#{post.id}']").click
```

(note the leading . without that no scoping will work, get used to putting it there when using xpath expressions - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#beware-the-xpath--trap) which would actually read better and be much less brittle as

```
click_link(href: post_path(post))
```

although verifying hrefs in a feature test isn't best practice.  You'd be better off clicking the link based on the text shown in it

```
click_link(post.name) #whatever is actually shown on the page
```

Comment: I've tried using let!, also tried using `create` instead of build, but didn't work

Comment: I changed my code `find()...` like yours and can't find the id now `Unable to find xpath "//a[@href='/articles/']"`

Comment: definitely needs to be create too - I missed that in my review - otherwise it won't be saved and wont show on your page.  Update your example to your current code.

Comment: @Lykos You updated it to be like which one of mine? and where is /articles/ coming from? Is the route for posts not /posts/xxx ?

Comment: Sorry, my bad its posts not articles. I copied wrong code :-)

Comment: @Lykos  When you use `let!(:post) { create(:post) }` what is the error then?

Comment: Do I need to create a dynamic id too? because now its complaining for ambiguous match `Ambiguous match, found 2 elements matching xpath "//a[@href='/posts/1']"` and if so, how can I fix this?

Comment: Huh?  Look at `page.html` do you have two links with the same hrefs? - and I assume you mean /posts/ and not /articles/  -  Also - update your question so it has the actual code you're now running.

Comment: By page.html do you mean the page that lists all posts (index action)? This supposed to have just this post created from the factory, right?

Comment: I mean do `puts page.html` and look at the output it generates, you could also do save_and_open_page but from your other question you're obviously having issues getting any of that to work

Comment: Did an update on the code, please review. I did puts page.html and this is what was rendered in terminal. Also did `save_and_open_page` and shows the page rendered without any errors. Btw thanks for the feedback on my other issue!

Comment: The code in the question doesn't appear to have changed, but from the output you can see that you do have two links that have the same href --  the 'Show' link and the 'Destroy' link --  assuming you're trying to follow the 'Show' link do    `click_link('Show', href: post_path(post))`  rather than find(...).click

Comment: @Lykos I have no clue what you're doing, you keep swapping between /posts/ and /articles/ and for some reason refuse to update the code in your question to what you are actually using -  I can't help anymore

Comment: Nevermind fixed it! it was a typo, thank you a lot for your help! I've already accepted your answer, however if you want to do an update in your code [ replace find()... with click_link('Show', href: post_path(post)) ] so that it looks more clear the solution. Again thanks and sorry for confusing you with posts and articles, I was working on 2 tasks with same problem